# Distutils package name

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I am packaging a python package using distutils.

My structure looks like this:

```
src
\  __init__.py
 | util.py
 | client
   \  __init__.py
    | file1.py
    | file2.py
```

In setup.py my package is:

```
package_dir={'pkg_name':'src'},
packages=['pkg_name','pkg_name.client']
```

I would like to be able to use the content of `client` without out having to import `pkg_name.client`, but just by importing `pkg`.

Is that possible? I just read https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages. The examples I saw are still all referencing the directory name (or a different one). But is it possible to remove that, and just have it included in root? I've tried a bunch of variations but they are all failing.

Something like `package_dir = {'': 'src', '': 'src/client'}`

In python, the directory name that **init** will still need to be referenced but I am hoping `distutil` has some trick around that.

Answer (score 0):

When I first packaged, I also tried a bunch of variations, will get it working.

If your directory structure can be changed, my suggestion is to use a tool I created to myself and made it public, called machete. There are others, like cookiecutter.

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/machete/
```

In a empty folder, you just type:

```
/home/you $ machete -t app
```

This will generate all the structure needed, and you just need to understand its logic, and fill it with code. The structure is very different from yours, because a package has some needs.

Creating a package for the first time is kind of frustrating.

Aditionally, one tricky thing machete does is to add this on modules folder:

```
file: __init__.py

# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import glob

__all__ = []

py_files = glob.glob('./yourproject/modules/*.py')
py_files.remove('./yourproject/modules/__init__.py')
for py_file in py_files:
    __all__.append(py_file.split('/')[3].split('.')[0])
```

This way, importing modules.*, perhaps you can achieve your goal with your directory structure. This one works for machete generated projects.

Hope one of my suggestions helps you out.

Marco